# Unpivot table and join on condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, unpivot

I have 2 tables:

Funds

```
country   2002     2006    2010   2014
Chicago   1000    23000    4500   9076
```

Medals

```
year   sport   event    country   gender   medal_rank  medal
2006    A        Z      Chicago    F          2         silver
1924    B        ZZ     Newyork    M          3         bronze
2014    C        ZZZZ   Chicago    M          1         Gold
1967    B        ZZb    Newyork    M          3         bronze
2014    C        ZZa    Chicago    F          2         silver
```

I want to unpivot data in Funds like

```
country    year    value
Chicago    2002    1000
Chicago    2006    23000
Chicago    2010    4500
Chicago    2014    9076
```

and then join with Medals, only bringing the count of the medal column for years 2002, 2006, 2010 and 2104, because we only have values for those years in Funds.
In the final step I divide value/countofmedal as value/medal.

The final table should look like:

```
country    year    value     countofmedeals      value/medal
Chicago    2002    1000        0                     0
Chicago    2006    23000       1                     23000
Chicago    2010    4500        0                     0
Chicago    2014    9076        2                     4536
```

Below is the code I tried but it's not working.

```
use RDG

select
    S.Yr,
    qu.year,
    s.Cost,
    count(qu.medal)
from
(
    select 
        country,
        yr, 
        Cost
    from Funds
    unpivot
    (
        Yr for Cost in ([2002],[2006],[2010],[2014])
    ) as u
) s
join medals qu
on (s.country=qu.country and s.Yr=qu.year)
group by s.Yr,qu.year,s.Cost
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Also re line breaks. Please do not ask for priority.

Comment: What is your question? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Funds table
(
    country varchar(20),
    [2002] int,
    [2006] int,
    [2010] int,
    [2014] int
);
insert into @Funds(country, [2002], [2006], [2010], [2014])
values ('Chicago', 1000, 23000, 4500, 9076);


declare @Medals table
(
year int,
sport varchar(20),
event varchar(20),
country varchar(20),
gender char(1),
medal_rank tinyint,
medal varchar(20)
);
insert into @Medals(year, sport, event, country, gender, medal_rank, medal)
values
(2006, 'A', 'Z', 'Chicago', 'F', 2, 'silver'),
(1924, 'B', 'ZZ', 'Newyork', 'M', 3, 'bronze'),
(2014, 'C', 'ZZZZ', 'Chicago', 'M', 1, 'Gold'),
(1967, 'B', 'ZZb', 'Newyork', 'M', 3, 'bronze'),
(2014, 'C', 'ZZa', 'Chicago', 'F', 2, 'silver');

select
    S.country,
    S.Yr,
    qu.year /*??*/,
    s.value,
    count(qu.medal) as countofmedals,
    cast(isnull(s.value*1./nullif(count(qu.medal), 0), 0) as decimal(19,2)) as [value/medal]
from
(
    select 
        country,
        yr, 
        value
    from @Funds
    unpivot
    (
        value for yr in ([2002],[2006],[2010],[2014]) --!!!!
    ) as u
) s
left join @medals qu --!!!!
on (s.country=qu.country and s.Yr=qu.year)
group by s.country, s.Yr,qu.year/*??*/,s.value;
```